# My question is related to remainder of powers of number

Tags: number-theory

How to find the minimum $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$(2^n-1)^k \equiv x \pmod{m}$$

Comment: For $n=0$ or $n=1$ or $m\mid 2^n-1$ or $m\mid 2^n-2$ or $m\mid 2^n$, you will have a hard time when trying to solve this for all $x$

Comment: @Sarthak If you wish to keep this question open, you are supposed to add your efforts in solving this problem to the question body.

Comment: I tried using properties such as (a^k)%m=(a%m)^k but that does not lead to any concrete result.I did try solving for a few values,

Comment: n=4,x=2,m=17 which gave an answer that it give an answer that it is not possible to find a k in this case

Comment: Cases for which I did get an answer was n=2,m=7,x=2 which gave k=2